# How to save marker location in SQLite and create another activity on that location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I have an application where currently after clicking on a location, a marker pops up showing its latitude and longitude.

[image: **enter image description here**]

I want to be able to click on that marker and save its location data in my SQLite database. After the location is saved, I want that location in my Google Maps to be highlighted. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by highlighted?

Comment: @ZahidRasheed what I meant was that after saving a GPS coordinate (i.e. a particular place's latitude and longitude, I wanted the map to pin point that location and each time places are saved, the map would show those places, either highlighted as a different color or circles. Can you please tell me how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to implement like below code where MarkerInfoWindowAdapter will display popup on click of marker.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {    
            setUpMap();
            displayLocationOnMap();
        }

     private void setUpMap()
            {

                if (mMap == null)
                {
                    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();

                    if (mMap != null)
                    {
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker)
                            {
                                marker.showInfoWindow();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

    private void displayLocationOnMap()
    {
    Marker currentMarker = null;

                currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
 .title(Location)    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_view)));

                currentMarker.isInfoWindowShown();
                currentMarker.setVisible(true);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude(),longitude()), 8.0f));

                mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
    }


public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
    {
        public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_map_layout, null);

            MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

            TextView marker_latitude = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_latitude);

            TextView marker_longitude = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_longitude);



            marker_latitude.setText("Latitude :" + latitude);

            marker_longitude.setText("Longitude:" +longitude);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much! @Ragini

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
@Override
    public void setOnMarkerClickListner(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       System.out.println(" "
                + map.getMyLocation().getLongitude()+map.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
     //Your code to add to database..
    }
```

In the above code

```
map.getMyLocation().getLongitude()
```

gives you longitude and

```
map.getMyLocation().getLongitude()
```

gives you latitude.Then you will write your code to put it in your SQLite.
Hope that helps

Comment: thank you. while its correct but i wanted the information from the infoWindow on to another activity.

Comment: You will have to use intent for that..use intent and intent.putextra...Anyways reach out if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnMarkerClickListner to click on marker and inside onMarkerclick method write your logic to save longitude and latitude in database and write helper method to add marker on google map by using map.add(new MarkerOptions) which will read data from db

Answer (score 0):

You can save them as REAL values in a single table with an identifier and then reference them from the table you want.